# Linux Shell Pipeline Execution

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec, pipeline

I am trying to implement a basic linux shell with support for pipelining. However, my code seems to hang or just not execute programs and I can't figure out why.

```
if (list_empty(&job_list))
                            job_index = 1;

                        bool dopipe = false;
                        if (list_size(&pipeline->commands) > 1)
                            dopipe = true;

                        esh_signal_sethandler(SIGCHLD, signal_handler);
                        esh_signal_block(SIGCHLD);

                        setpgid(0, 0);
                        pipeline->pgrp = getpgid(0);
                        pipeline->jid = job_index++;

                        list_push_back(&job_list, &pipeline->elem);

                        bool background = pipeline->bg_job;

                        pid_t pid;

                        if ( (pid = fork()) == 0)
                        {
                            //Child

                            if (pipeline->bg_job)
                                setpgid(0, 0);

                            int oldpipe[2];
                            int newpipe[2];

                            int count = 0;
                            int size = list_size(&pipeline->commands);

                            struct list_elem * current_job;

                            printf("SIZE: %zu\n", list_size(&pipeline->commands));

                            for (current_job = list_begin(&pipeline->commands); current_job != list_tail(&pipeline->commands); current_job = list_next(current_job))
                            {   
                                if (count < size)
                                    pipe(newpipe);

                                pid_t fpid = fork();
                                printf("fpid: %d\n", (int)fpid);
                                if (fpid == 0)
                                {
                                    //Child
                                    printf("Executing Child\n");
                                    if (count > 0)
                                    {
                                        //prev command exists
                                        dup2(oldpipe[0], 0);
                                        close(oldpipe[0]);
                                        close(oldpipe[1]);
                                    }

                                    if (count < size - 1)
                                    {
                                        //next command exists
                                        close(newpipe[0]);
                                        dup2(newpipe[1], 1);
                                        close(newpipe[1]);
                                    }

                                    esh_command* cmd = list_entry(current_job, struct esh_command, elem);

                                    printf("Running: %s %s\n", cmd->argv[0], cmd->argv[1]);

                                    if (execvp(cmd->argv[0], cmd->argv) < 0)
                                        esh_sys_fatal_error("Program Does Not Exist\n");
                                }
                                else
                                {   
                                    //Parent

                                    //*
                                    int status = 0;
                                    if (waitpid(fpid, &status, 0) < 0)
                                        esh_sys_fatal_error("Could not fork pipe\n");
                                    //*/
                                    printf("Parent\n");

                                    if (count > 0)
                                    {
                                        //prev command exists
                                        close(oldpipe[0]);
                                        close(oldpipe[1]);
                                    }

                                    if (count < size - 1)
                                    {
                                        //next command exists
                                        oldpipe[0] = newpipe[0];
                                        oldpipe[1] = newpipe[1];
                                    }

                                    printf("End of Parent\n");
                                }
                                count++;
                            }

                            if (size > 1)
                            {
                                close(oldpipe[0]);
                                close(oldpipe[1]);
                            }
                            printf("Finished Pipeline\n");
                            exit(3);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //*
                            int status = 0;
                            commands->pid = pid;

                            //Parent
                            if (!background)
                            {
                                pipeline->status = FOREGROUND;
                                if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
                                    printf("waitpid ERROR\n");

                                list_remove(&pipeline->elem);
                            }
                            else
                                pipeline->status = BACKGROUND;
                            //*/
                        }

                    esh_signal_unblock(SIGCHLD);
```

I am fairly certain the error has to do with either the piping, or the forking of child processes in the loop.

Comment: I would step through the code to figure out where it stops. (`bash -x script`)

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and use `strace` on your shell and some other shell. Also, study the code of some simple free software shell like `sash`

Comment: Also, learn how to use your debugger (so compile with `gcc -Wall -g` then use `gdb`). And please indent your code (perhaps with the `indent sourcefile.c` command).

Comment: Are you sure that `waitpid` is necessary in the parent of the `exec`'d process? It looks like your hang may be caused by the parent waiting for the first child to exit, which it won't because there are still open file descriptors that are waiting to be piped into the next process.